# How to setup ZohoDesk & Identity Server?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, zoho

I have a problem with this connection.
I have a method Login(). The method catches user data with form. But I don`t know how get token and then it send to zoho desk.
My clients settings:

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId = "zoho.com",
                ClientName = "Zoho Desk",
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference,
                AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,

                Enabled = true,
                RequireConsent = false,
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,

                ClientUri = "zoho.com",
                BackChannelLogoutUri = $"{coreSettings.ZohoSamlRequestUrl}",
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = postLogoutRedirectUris,
                RedirectUris = {$"{coreSettings.ZohoSamlResponseUrl}"},

                RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
                RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,

                IdentityTokenLifetime = 300,
                AuthorizationCodeLifetime = 300,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 3600,
                AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = coreSettings.AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetimeInSeconds,

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    StandardScopes.Email,
                    StandardScopes.Profile
                }
            }
```

I get message "Invalid SAML Response received." after redirect to https://accounts.zohoportal.com/accounts/csamlresponse/xxxxxxx

Comment: IdentityServer4 is an OAuth2/OIDC IDP, not a SAML IDP. But you can add support for SAML with extensions like SAML2P: https://www.identityserver.com/articles/saml-20-integration-with-identityserver4

Comment: Alternatively, configure your Zoho account to use OIDC instead of SAML: https://www.zoho.com/accounts/protocol/oauth-setup.html

Comment: Thanks, @Dai. Do you know free SAML lib?

Comment: @ViktorBylbas here it is: https://www.itfoxtec.com/identitysaml2

Answer (score 0):

SAML is paid option for IDS4 https://www.identityserver.com/products/saml2p
However, there is a free alternative https://www.itfoxtec.com/identitysaml2